# Need a advise regarding why to use SMTP?

Tags: node.js, forms, express, email, nodemailer

I made a contact form on my website and need to submit it to my proton mail using Node.JS and express.

Do I need an SMTP server? Can I do it without SMTP or not? Because it'll be very focused and not that big. It'll only send forms to my email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) is an internet standard
> communication protocol for electronic mail transmission. Mail servers
> and other message transfer agents use SMTP to send and receive mail
> messages.

SMTP is a mail transport system and yes, is required to send email.

You can either set up a send-only mail server (e.g Postfix Mailserver), or use the general purpose [sendmail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendmail) if you are just sending email to yourself.

You can also use your own email/password with nodejs, if you use gmail/yahoo etc, as long as you get your settings right.